# Trying to get the count of items per day with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a db with several days of data and I want to get the count of each record with Status=0, Status=1...Status=8 for each day. I was to see something like.

```
DateAndTime      State_0    State_1   State_2
2014-08-15           5          8        9
2014-08-16           2          5        6
2014-08-17           4          2        3
```

I was trying this:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(dd,(DATEDIFF(dd,0,DateAndTime)),0) AS DateAndTime,
       SUM( Case When State=0 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS State_0,
       SUM( Case When State=1 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS State_1,
       SUM( Case When State=2 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS State_2
           FROM [DB_002].[dbo].[MyDb]
   Group By DateAndTime
   Order by DateAndTime
```

But it keeps adding rows for each state that I add. That is with 3 states I'm getting 4 rows for each date. Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this MySQL, but based on the syntax of the query this is Microsoft SQL Server.  Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

You are grouping on the `DateAndTime` field, which contains also the time component. That makes each record practically unique, so there will be a single record in each group.

Group on the date only:

```
Group By DATEADD(dd,(DATEDIFF(dd,0,DateAndTime)),0)
Order by DATEADD(dd,(DATEDIFF(dd,0,DateAndTime)),0)
```

Comment: It may also be enough to cast the value to `DATE` (which should truncate the time part).

Answer (score 0):

You are confused because you have changed a column and given it the same name as the original column.  When you say `group by DateAndTime`, that is referring to the column in the table.  Assuming this is SQL Server, I would write the query as something like this:

```
   SELECT cast(d.DateAndTime as Date) as DateAndNoTime,
          SUM(Case When d.State = 0 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS State_0,
          SUM(Case When d.State = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS State_1,
          SUM(Case When d.State = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) AS State_2
   FROM [DB_002].[dbo].[MyDb] d
   Group By cast(d.DateAndTime as Date)
   Order by DateAndNoTime;
```

This changes the name of the alias in the `select` to avoid confusion.  It uses the alias for column references, to also clarify the meaning of the query.  And, it uses `cast()` instead of the old `datedd`/`datediff` trick.